# how to create a new method based on editorformodel html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new in MVC and I need to modify EditorForModel for using permissions (show/Not show, disabled/Enable, etc) in the fields from my DB, according with kind of user. Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom editors for your models by adding a EditorTemplates folder in your Views/Shared folder. More info about this process can be found here – http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx

Comment: Good and how can I pass and receive IEnumerable Model to this new template ? I need this for rendering editorfor all fields according with its permission.